# how to handle timeout error in selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

When i am running automation on Chrome browser with Chrome Version as 75.0.3770.100 and chromedriver as 2.40.0, then i can see page keeps on loading and throwing "The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:42607/session timed out after 60 seconds". how to handle this situation.

Comment: i updated chromedriver(75) to latest version, still i am facing the same issue

Comment: Can you post the code that initializes the ChromeDriver object?